# get all transfer events with getPastEvents that are from or to an address

Tags: web3js, tokens

i want to get all the events transfer from a erc20 token , that has a relation with an address either he send tokens or he recived them ,but filter with both fields with the same addres  is like an &&

the ref i've used
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents

this is my code

```
contract
      .getPastEvents("Transfer", {
        filter: {
          from: useraccounts[0],
          to: useraccounts[0]
        },
        fromBlock: 0,
        toBlock: "latest",
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```